# How to multiply tensors of different shapes? (broadcasting)

Tags: tensorflow

I want to multiple the elements in a tensor of shape [a,b,c], each in the 3rd dimension with a scalar from a tensor of shape [a,b].

For example,

```
x = 
|[1,2][3,4][5,6]|
|[1,2][3,4][5,6]|
|[1,2][3,4][5,6]|

y = 
|0 0 1|
|1 0 0|
|0 1 0|
```

I want to multiply x and y to obtain:

```
res = 
|[0,0][0,0][5,6]|
|[1,2][0,0][0,0]|
|[0,0][3,4][0,0]|
```

Could you tell me any method to achieve this?

P.S: maybe I can make a `y'` from `y` which is

```
y' =
|[0,0][0,0][1,1]|
|[1,1][0,0][0,0]|
|[0,0][1,1][0,0]|
```

then I can use `tf.mul()` to obtain the result. But I don't find anything to duplicate elements in a tensor in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you can just use `tf.mul()`. In fact, the multiply operation in TensorFlow handles [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), so you don't need to create another vector of shape `[a, b, c]`.

To make sure that the broadcasting is on the expected dimension, you can add a third dimension to your second vector `y`:

```py
x = tf.random_normal([3, 3, 2])
y = tf.constant([[0., 0., 1.], [1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]])

y = tf.expand_dims(y, 2)  # y will now have a matching shape of [3, 3, 1]
res = tf.mul(x, y)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(res)
```